# How do I satisfy these conditions in my loop for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find the engagement rate for each data row and then find the video title with the highest engagement rate.

'row' in the dict youtube_usa_videos consist of many elements of which the index for each element has been named. The problem arises when I try to set the condition as seen below which python gives 'division by zero' error message as there are some views that are zero in the data set.

Engagement rate = no. of comments / no. of views

```
#code below

highest_EGR = 0

for row in youtube_usa_videos:

    comments = row [8]
    views = row [5]
    title = row [1]

    if views != 0:
        EGR = comments / views
    else:
        EGR = 0

    If EGR > highest_EGR:
        highest_EGR = EGR
        top_vid = title
```

Can you help me clean my code such that the conditions will be met and the top video title and its engagement rate will be printed?

Comment: In order to help you, we need you to precise what do you mean by *"The problem arises"*.

Comment: It's not clear what your data is like. I would recommend the following: get the data as a pandas dataframe, and simply make an extra "EGR" row, then sort the data by EGR to see videos with most engagement. The basic pandas documentation and SO questions already asked should get you there.

Comment: Please explain what is wrong

Comment: Hi yes my bad. With the above code, the issue is that I get 'division by zero' so python would not calculate the EGR. This is because there are some views that are 0 and my conditions set some how doesn't filter out those views that are 0

Answer (score 0):

The code below works well.

Consider replacing `If`  with `if`

```
highest_EGR = 0

youtube_usa_videos = [['t1',12,45],['t2',34,12],['t3',2,123]]
TITLE_OFFSET = 0
VIEWS_OFFSET = 1
COMMENTS_OFFSET = 2

for row in youtube_usa_videos:

    comments = row [COMMENTS_OFFSET]
    views = row [VIEWS_OFFSET]
    title = row [TITLE_OFFSET]

    if views != 0:
        EGR = comments / views
    else:
        EGR = 0

    if EGR > highest_EGR:
        highest_EGR = EGR
        top_vid = title 
print('highest_EGR: {}'.format(highest_EGR))
# or using max and lambda
max_egr = max(youtube_usa_videos,key=lambda vid:vid[COMMENTS_OFFSET] / vid[VIEWS_OFFSET] if vid[VIEWS_OFFSET] else 0)
print('video with max eger: {}'.format(max_egr))
```

output

```
highest_EGR: 61.5
video with max eger: ['t3', 2, 123]
```

Answer (score 0):

highest_EGR = 0

for row in youtube_usa_videos:

```
comments = row [8]
views = row [5]
title = row [1]

if int (views) > 0:
    EGR = int (comments) / int (views)

if EGR > highest_EGR:
    highest_EGR = EGR
    top_vid = title 
print (top_vid, highest_EGR)
```

Okay I simply changed 'if views != 0:' to 'if views > 0:' and removed 'else:'